# Swift 3 Saving array with UserDefaults

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save an array to UserDefaults, but after running the app displays this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saEb6.png). When the app crashes, Xcode displays correct values of the array, so the data are saved well into the array.
I save the string data to array in first VC :

```
 Last20Times.insert(dsa, at: 0) // Last20Times is the array.
 if Last20Times.count > 0 {
   let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
   defaults.set(Last20Times, forKey: "last20")
```

Second controller is TableView:

```
 if indexPath.section == 1 {
   let ArrayLast20 = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "last20")
   cell.textLabel?.text = ArrayLast20?[indexPath.row]// error(picture)
 }

return cell
```

Thank you

Comment: On which line did the error occur? What is shown in the console?

Comment: You don't seriously get data from user defaults in `cellForRow`, don't you? User defaults is not supposed to be used for saving temporary data. Pass the data via the segue or protocol / delegate or block.

Comment: @vadian It is a part of a game, where I save his last 20 results into Tableviewcontroller

Comment: @Sweeper The console shows the array including correct elements, i tagged error line in my question

Answer (score -1):

You need to save your UserDefaults as such:

```
defaults.synchronize()
```

. . .

Comment: You actually don't.

Comment: @vadian can you elaborate? How do you save userdefaults without sync?

Comment: From the documentation: *Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes.*

Comment: " -synchronize is deprecated and will be marked with the NS_DEPRECATED macro in a future release." - Documentation